# Essential singularity of composition of complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

Suppose $f(z)$ - entire function and $g(z)$ has essential singularity at $z=a$.
What type of singularity can have $f(g(z))$ at $z=a$?

Comment: By [Casorati-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) the image of $g(D_r(a)\setminus \{a\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ and consequently the composition with an entire function $f \circ g(D_r(a)\setminus \{a\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, for all $r > 0$. Thus the singularity at $a$ must be essential.

Comment: @r9m Right, except for trivial counterexamples, which one should really specify to give a strictly correct statement...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes I should have mentioned $f$ being non-constant (the comment was meant to nudge the OP in direction of a solution .. )